# tcpdump missing on Cygwin v1.7.7 for packet sniffing

Tags: cygwin, tcp, packet, sniffing, tcpdump

I am trying to debug why my TCP packets are truncated. I see that only the first 24 bytes of each packet are showing up in my program.  The 25th through 28th bytes are scrambled and all others after that are zeroed out.

I'd like to run tcpdump to try and debug what is going wrong but it is missing in the Cygwin install.

Can anyone suggest an alternative to tcpdump or ideas on how I might go about debugging this?

The issue occurs for both read and write of packets to a known platfrom (Linux) that works fine.  It also occurs when read or write to self via localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Wireshark v1.4.3 which gives you a GUI to look at network traffic.